# .htaccess subfolder not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I've looked everywhere to try and solve this and I can't get any of the solutions elsewhere to work.

I have a drupal website running on a domain

I have build a new website in `www.domain.com/subfolder`

In a .htaccess file in the sub folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?login$ /index.php?get_action=login [L]
```

However when I try and visit www.domain.com/subfolder/login I get redirected to the www.domain.com.

I need `www.domain.com/subfolder/login` to redirect to `www.domain.com/subfolder/index.php?get_action=login`

How do I accomplish this.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of drupal and instead of using the .htaccess file , I would install Drupal's Login destination module . You can find it here -> http://drupal.org/project/login_destination . I hope it helps .

Comment: The new site isn't drupal. D

Answer (score 0):

If your htaccess file is in the subfolder, you can try adding a rewrite base and remove the leading slashes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?get_action=login [L]
```

Or, you can explicitly make the target an absolute URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?login$ /subfolder/index.php?get_action=login [L]
```